# Dissect my jQuery - can't use keyup function to insert number of characters into another textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out why my jQuery isn't working. I've got jQuery linked to, and then after that, I try to bind to the textarea content. I've used name=content and name=#content both.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[name=content]').bind('keyup',function(){
     $('#desctag').val($(this).length)
});
</script>
```

Why isn't it working?

Code is now:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('input[name=#content]').bind('keyup',function(){
 $('#desctag').val($(this).length)
})})
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in a document.ready function so it executes when the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('input[name=content]').bind('keyup',function(){
          $('#desctag').val($(this).length);
     });
});
```

Comment: @AndrewAlexander did you put the semi-colon after `$('#desctag').val($(this).length); <--`